# time diff() in php with data in sql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a table in sql like this

| id | data | time_in |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-01-17 | 16:41:25.00000 |

Now I would like now the differce in hours from data-time_in and today-now
I try :

```
$ora_uscita=date("H:i:s"); 
$in  = new DateTime($time_in);
$out = new DateTime($ora_uscita);
$interval = $out->diff($in);
```

but I have problem with to do it with data

Comment: What problem do you have? Does it give an error message, produce no results, or produce results that you weren't expecting?

Comment: `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TIMESTAMP(data, time_in), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM tablename WHERE ...` will give the needed difference in complete hours amount.